# Equivalent characterizations of Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have two characterizations of Dedekind domains, namely

1) Every nonzero proper ideal of $A$ is invertible, and $Q \neq A$, where $Q$ is a field of fractions

2) $A$ is a Noetherian ring and it has Krull dimension one. Also, $A$ is integrally closed in $Q$.

To prove 1) => 2) I proved that every prime ideal is maximal, which shows that every chain of prime ideals has length one. But I do not know, how to show that then $A$ is Noetherian and that it is integrally closed.

For 2) => 1) I completely have no idea.

Could you help me please to prove these equivalences? I also heard about the trick of considering a polynomial ring as a fractional ideal to prove 1) => 2), but this didn't help a lot. Could you please as well provide some good sources like books, where this topic is covered (and I suppose that this equivalence is proven in many places).

Answer (score 0):

For "1) => $A$ noetherian" you could prove that every integral ideal of $A$ is finitely generated. See [1] if you like. The fact that $A$ is noetherian also shows, that it is sufficient to assume that every integral ideal is invertible to show that every fractional ideal is invertible.

For "1) => $A$ integrally closed let $x\in Q$ satisfy $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n=0$ with $a_1,...a_n \in A$. Consider $\mathfrak{a}=(1,x,\dots ,x^{n-1})$, then $x\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ invertible shows $x\in A$.

For "2) => 1)" you may for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ define the fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}^*$ by

> $\mathfrak{a}^* = \{x \in Q \mid x\mathfrak{a}\subset A\}$

in order to show that $\mathfrak{a}^*$ is the inverse of $\mathfrak{a}$.

For a more detailed proof you may want to have a look at [2].

[1] http://www.mathreference.com/id-dd,fingen.html

[2] http://planetmath.org/proofthatadomainisdedekindifitsidealsareinvertible